# How to add another condition to a specific active facet?

Tags: search

I did try to add a condition using hook_views_pre_execute or hook_views_query_alter, but since Im usiong SearchAPI, theres is no point apparently in using these functions (no $query in views_query_alter, and no query too in views_pre_execute

Maybe using hook__search_api_query_alter could d othe trick but I dont know how to implement it.

My question is : How can I achieve this ?

Knowing that I need to add anoteh condition only when items of a specific facet are active (among a few other facets).

Comment: I did find a simple solution using views UI and a new filter. No need to add a SQL condition.

I have to put a filter using a specific field with the condition "IS NOT EMPTY". The if results do not validate my condition, they arent displayed.

This is what I wanted but now I need to add this filter only when a specific facet has active item(s).

Comment: Ive managed to add my filter using hook_search_api_query_alter and the code
$base_filter = $query->createFilter('AND');
$base_filter->condition('field_produit_ingredients:format', NULL, "<>");
$query->filter($base_filter);

But I don't know how to add this filter only when the specific filter is active.

Theres a lot of things in $query ... so much that I can't dsm() it. And print_r rendering is so ugly !

Comment: I could do that using FacetApiAdapter functions (http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!facetapi!plugins!facetapi!adapter.inc/class/FacetapiAdapter/7) ... I need help to be able to use one of these function within hook_search_api_query_alter. 
Anyone knows how to ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple :

```
function mymodule_search_api_query_alter(SearchApiQueryInterface $query) {
    if(preg_match('/PRETTYPATHID/',url($_GET['q']))){
        $base_filter = $query->createFilter('AND');
        $base_filter->condition('MYFIELD', NULL, "<>");
        $query->filter($base_filter);
    }

}
```

Comment: The Facets module lets you make facets dependent on other facets.